# Backup a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, backup

I want to backup my DB but I got a error:

> ConnectionStrings cannot be used like a method

How can I resolve this?

```
string strCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
string sSQL = "BACKUP DATABASE Database TO DISK = 'D:\\Database.bak';";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings(strCon).ConnectionString)) 
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should directly use that variable as `SqlConnection` requires a string object containing a connection string and you are storing it in a string object itself.

So it would be simply like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strCon)) 
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Recommended: (to store it in `Web.config`)

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="job" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then access it like this: (`using System.Configuration;`)

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["job"].ConnectionString
```

Comment: now i got this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.

Comment: You have used `database` keyword 2 times, so replace 2nd one with your database name. so finally it would be: `BACKUP DATABASE @Your_db TO DISK = 'D:\\Database.bak';`

Comment: What is the database name you want to take backup..?.

Comment: I have edit my Web.config file and I set   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["job"].ConnectionString))
But I keep getting this error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.

Comment: Hi @Vishal Suthar Database.mdf

Comment: I renamed my database to BakupDB.mdf and now I got this error:
Database 'BakupDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Please use correct name of the database. Use this to get it: `select name from sys.databases;`

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionStrings` is a collection. It must be used like:

```
ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings[0].ConnectionString
```

Comment: Are you trying to get your connection string from configuration file? Cause I can see that you already have it in the `strCon` variable. See @Vishal Suthar's answer